# How to fill a hollow object generated from solidify modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I have a vertebrae with solidify modifier applied, I need to generate another vertebrae which perfectly fits the inside of the solidified one. I have been trying the Boolean modifier by simply experimenting on a solidified cube, trying to cut a cube of the same dimension using the difference option but no luck.

Comment: hello, please show some screenshots, maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this misunderstands the question:

- Duplicate the solidified vertebra
- Apply the Solidify modifier
- Select one of the outside faces, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> select the rest, and delete
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> > flip the normals of the inside faces.

Comment: I checked the `Flip Normals` option while applying the solidify modifier and then deleted the outside faces

Comment: @S.aad Thanks! I hadn't noticed you could do it that way.